# ClassCastException in Dispatcher servlet with something being null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I am seeing following exception in my system log.

```
2019-09-09T07:08:09.491Z [priority='WARN' thread='TaskScheduler-5' user='' org='' trace=''] c.v.s.c.c.i.SlowRequestInterceptor - API call GET 'http://event:1234/event/api/subscriptions/broker-project-subscriber/poll/1' with response 200 OK took 420 ms.
2019-09-09T07:08:10.070Z [priority='INFO' thread='http-nio-8000-exec-10' user='-' org='-' trace='-'] GET /actuator/readiness HTTP/1.1 200 bytes='29' duration='2'
2019-09-09T07:08:11.070Z [priority='INFO' thread='http-nio-8000-exec-1' user='-' org='-' trace='-'] GET /readiness HTTP/1.1 200 bytes='29' duration='2'
2019-09-09T07:08:12.070Z [priority='INFO' thread='http-nio-8000-exec-2' user='-' org='-' trace='-'] GET /readiness HTTP/1.1 200 bytes='29' duration='2'
2019-09-09T07:08:12.696Z [priority='INFO' thread='TaskScheduler-3' user='' org='' trace=''] c.a.b.b.t.d.s.DeploymentProjectServiceImpl - Registering xxxx-service callbacks
2019-09-09T07:08:12.719Z [priority='INFO' thread='TaskScheduler-3' user='' org='' trace=''] c.a.b.b.xx.xx.gateway.XXXXXGateway - Registered callback for yyyyy-service-deployment.
2019-09-09T07:08:12.908Z [priority='WARN' thread='TaskScheduler-1' user='' org='' trace=''] c.v.s.c.c.i.SlowRequestInterceptor - API call GET 'http://event:1234/event/api/subscriptions/broker-project-subscriber/poll/1' with response 200 OK took 417 ms.
2019-09-09T07:08:13.070Z [priority='INFO' thread='http-nio-8000-exec-4' user='-' org='-' trace='-'] GET /readiness HTTP/1.1 200 bytes='29' duration='2'
2019-09-09T07:08:14.070Z [priority='INFO' thread='http-nio-8000-exec-6' user='-' org='-' trace='-'] GET /readiness HTTP/1.1 200 bytes='29' duration='2'
2019-09-09T07:08:15.071Z [priority='INFO' thread='http-nio-8000-exec-7' user='-' org='-' trace='-'] GET /readiness HTTP/1.1 200 bytes='29' duration='3'
2019-09-09T07:08:15.503Z [priority='ERROR' thread='http-nio-8000-exec-8' user='' org='' trace='3199f921d4ee6d75'] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException] with root cause
```

java.lang.ClassCastException: null

I have no clue on when it happens. It is coming from apache library. There is nothing before and after it. Could someone provide some, direction please ?

Comment: Can you share the complete stack trace of the exception so that we can see exactly where it's occurring?

Comment: Can you clean the project and rerun it again.

Comment: Updated the stack trace with full exception